# Navbar collapse not working - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm new on Bootstrap and Symfony. I'm trying to collapse this Navbar but is not working. Hope you can help me.

Here's the code:

The head

```
    <head>
<title> Title </title>

<meta name="Description" content="HINT"/>
<meta name="Distribution" content="global"/>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="author" content="content">
 <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('favicon.ico')}}">
<link href="{{asset('css/base-style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/slider.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jssor.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jssor.slider.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/dropdown.js')}}"></script>
```

And the navbar section

```
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
<!--
<div class = "logo">
  <img  src="{{asset('images/Logo.png')}}"></img>
</div>
-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>

      <div class="navbar-header">
            <button  class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding:0px;" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="{{asset('images/Logo.png')}}"/>
          </a>  
      </div> 

        <li class="active"><a href="{{ path('nucleo_homepage')}}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('nucleo_empresa')}}">Business</a></li>

        <li class="drop"> <a href="#">Servicios</a>

          <div class="dropdownContain">
            <div class="dropOut">

              <div  class="triangle"></div>
                 <div class="triangle-border"></div>
                  <ul>
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('1');">Head Hunting  </li>   
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('2');">Study</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('3');">Profiles</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('4');">Consultor&iacute;as</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('5');">Functions</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('6');">Interviews</a></li>  
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('7');">Matrix</a></li> 
                  </ul>
            </div>
          </div >
        </li>

        <li class="drop"> <a href="{{ path('nucleo_cv')}}"> TEXT </a>
         <div class="dropdownContain">
            <div class="dropOut">

             </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="drop"> <a href="{{ path('nucleo_contactos')}}">Contact us</a>
         <div class="dropdownContain">
            <div class="dropOut">

              <ul>

            </div>
         </div>
              </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
  </div>        
</nav>

       </div>
```

The button is shown, but it doesn't collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the target for the collapse. After you close the "navbar-header" add:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
   ... the rest of your navbar
</div>
```

See the example at the bottom of this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but the Navbar just keep collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Bootstrap 3, and you need jquery.js (less than version 3) and bootstrap.js to work on toggle functions.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMenu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>           
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">


      <div class="navbar-header">
            <button  class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding:0px;" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="{{asset('images/Logo.png')}}"/>
          </a>  
      </div> 
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ path('nucleo_homepage')}}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('nucleo_empresa')}}">Business</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown"> 

<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Servicios
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li onclick="urlservicios('1');">Head Hunting  </li>   
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('2');">Study</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('3');">Profiles</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('4');">Consultor&iacute;as</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('5');">Functions</li> 
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('6');">Interviews</a></li>  
                      <li onclick="urlservicios('7');">Matrix</a></li> 
        </ul>


        </li>
</ul

        <li class="drop"> <a href="{{ path('nucleo_cv')}}"> TEXT </a>
         <div class="dropdownContain">
            <div class="dropOut">

             </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="drop"> <a href="{{ path('nucleo_contactos')}}">Contact us</a>
         <div class="dropdownContain">
            <div class="dropOut">

              <ul>

            </div>
         </div>
              </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
  </div>        
</nav>
```